# Windows Form MDI Maximized Child on Windows 8

Tags: winforms, windows-8, mdi

I have a windows form app with a main form working as MDI container when i open an mdi child form and it have its WindowState as Maximized happend what you can see in the picture 1 the form is maximized but the border are show like in normal state anyway the button min, max and close are show in the mdi parent like happened when it show a maximized form.

After Restore and Maximize again it work fine as you can see in picture 2

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: *How* are you maximising the form intitially?

Comment: How is the datagridview bound to the form? (Do you change its size on form resize?)

Comment: datagrid is dock fill. Rowland you mean the parent mdi form or the child form?

Comment: I dont have a correct answer to this question yet, i'm just attacking my real problem right now letting the form in normal state and in the form load Maximizing it. that works